# Recursive SUM of childs to calculate another field in oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem to calculate sum of children for parent and parent is child for another parent.

I try to do it with CTE recursive but i stucked.

```
  create table table1 (ROWNRA varchar(10) ,
           CONTRACT_NO_A  varchar(100),
           START_DATE_A date,
           END_DATE_A date ,
           RISK_AMOUNT_A number (10,2)
           );
```

```
Insert into table1 (ROWNRA,CONTRACT_NO_A,START_DATE_A,END_DATE_A,RISK_AMOUNT_A) values  ('1','CON1',to_date('2017/04/06','YYYY/MM/DD'),to_date('2017/05/05','YYYY/MM/DD'),278000);
Insert into table1 (ROWNRA,CONTRACT_NO_A,START_DATE_A,END_DATE_A,RISK_AMOUNT_A) values ('2','CON2',to_date('2017/05/02','YYYY/MM/DD'),to_date('2017/06/01','YYYY/MM/DD'),123570.7);
Insert into table1 (ROWNRA,CONTRACT_NO_A,START_DATE_A,END_DATE_A,RISK_AMOUNT_A) values ('3','CON3',to_date('2017/05/02','YYYY/MM/DD'),to_date('2017/06/01','YYYY/MM/DD'),147664.12);
Insert into table1 (ROWNRA,CONTRACT_NO_A,START_DATE_A,END_DATE_A,RISK_AMOUNT_A) values ('4','CON4',to_date('2017/05/02','YYYY/MM/DD'),to_date('2017/06/01','YYYY/MM/DD'),183859.92);
Insert into table1 (ROWNRA,CONTRACT_NO_A,START_DATE_A,END_DATE_A,RISK_AMOUNT_A) values ('5','CON1',to_date('2017/05/06','YYYY/MM/DD'),to_date('2017/06/05','YYYY/MM/DD'),278000);
Insert into table1 (ROWNRA,CONTRACT_NO_A,START_DATE_A,END_DATE_A,RISK_AMOUNT_A) values ('6','CON2',to_date('2017/06/02','YYYY/MM/DD'),to_date('2017/07/01','YYYY/MM/DD'),123570.7);
Insert into table1 (ROWNRA,CONTRACT_NO_A,START_DATE_A,END_DATE_A,RISK_AMOUNT_A) values ('7','CON3',to_date('2017/06/02','YYYY/MM/DD'),to_date('2017/07/01','YYYY/MM/DD'),147664.12);
Insert into table1 (ROWNRA,CONTRACT_NO_A,START_DATE_A,END_DATE_A,RISK_AMOUNT_A) values ('8','CON4',to_date('2017/06/02','YYYY/MM/DD'),to_date('2017/07/01','YYYY/MM/DD'),183859.92);
```

My code:

```
with cte (rownra, contract_no_A, start_date_A, end_date_A,  risk_amount_A, lvl,  rownrB, risk_cumul)
    as (select rownra, contract_no_A, start_date_A, end_date_A,  risk_amount_A, 0 as lvl, rownra as rownrb, risk_amount_A as  risk_cumul
        from table1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT PAR.rownra, CTE.contract_no_A, par.start_date_A, par.end_date_A,  cte.risk_amount_A , CTE.lvl +1 AS LVL, cte.ROWNRB,
                par.risk_amount_A + CTE.risk_cumul
             -- cte.risk_cumul 
        FROM table1 PAR, CTE CTE
        WHERE  PAR.rownra > CTE.rownra
                      and PAR.start_date_A <= CTE.end_date_A-- (+) 
        AND CTE.LVL=0
        )


  ,t2 as ( select * from (
    select rownra, contract_no_A, start_date_A, end_date_A,  sum(risk_amount_A) over (partition by rownra) cumulativa_RA, rownrb ,
    case when sum(risk_amount_A) over (partition by rownra)*0.9-500000<0 then 0
                else 
              sum(risk_amount_A) over (partition by rownra)*0.9-500000
                end reinsured
    from cte)
    where rownra=rownrb)

,cte2 (ROWNRA,  CONTRACT_NO_A,  START_DATE_A,   END_DATE_A,  CUMULATIVA_RA,     ROWNRB, REINSURED,LVL)
as (select ROWNRA,  CONTRACT_NO_A,  START_DATE_A,   END_DATE_A,  CUMULATIVA_RA,     ROWNRB, REINSURED, 0 AS LVL
      from t2
      union ALL

      SELECT T_2.ROWNRA,    CTE_2.CONTRACT_NO_A,    T_2.START_DATE_A,   T_2.END_DATE_A,  T_2.CUMULATIVA_RA,     CTE_2.ROWNRB,   T_2.REINSURED, CTE_2.LVL+1

      FROM T2 T_2, CTE2 CTE_2
      WHERE T_2.rownra > CTE_2.rownra
                      and T_2.start_date_A <= CTE_2.end_date_A
                         AND CTE_2.LVL=0
)
SELECT * FROM CTE2
ORDER BY ROWNRA, LVL
```

My result (not desired)

```
ROWNRA|CONTRACT_NO_A|START_DATE_A|END_DATE_A|RISK_AMOUNT_A|LVL|ROWNRB|RISK_CUMUL
ROWNRA|CONTRACT_NO_A|START_DATE_A|END_DATE_A|CUMULATIVA_RA|ROWNRB|REINSURED|LVL
1|CON1|2017/04/06|2017/05/05|278000|1|0|0
2|CON2|2017/05/02|2017/06/01|401570,7|2|0|0
2|CON1|2017/05/02|2017/06/01|401570,7|1|0|1
3|CON3|2017/05/02|2017/06/01|549234,82|3|0|0
3|CON2|2017/05/02|2017/06/01|549234,82|2|0|1
3|CON1|2017/05/02|2017/06/01|549234,82|1|0|1
4|CON4|2017/05/02|2017/06/01|733094,74|4|159785,266|0
4|CON1|2017/05/02|2017/06/01|733094,74|1|159785,266|1
4|CON3|2017/05/02|2017/06/01|733094,74|3|159785,266|1
4|CON2|2017/05/02|2017/06/01|733094,74|2|159785,266|1
5|CON1|2017/05/06|2017/06/05|733094,74|5|159785,266|0
5|CON4|2017/05/06|2017/06/05|733094,74|4|159785,266|1
5|CON3|2017/05/06|2017/06/05|733094,74|3|159785,266|1
5|CON2|2017/05/06|2017/06/05|733094,74|2|159785,266|1
6|CON2|2017/06/02|2017/07/01|401570,7|6|0|0
6|CON1|2017/06/02|2017/07/01|401570,7|5|0|1
7|CON3|2017/06/02|2017/07/01|549234,82|7|0|0
7|CON1|2017/06/02|2017/07/01|549234,82|5|0|1
7|CON2|2017/06/02|2017/07/01|549234,82|6|0|1
8|CON4|2017/06/02|2017/07/01|733094,74|8|159785,266|0
8|CON2|2017/06/02|2017/07/01|733094,74|6|159785,266|1
8|CON1|2017/06/02|2017/07/01|733094,74|5|159785,266|1
8|CON3|2017/06/02|2017/07/01|733094,74|7|159785,266|1
```

Desired result:

```
ROWNRA|CONTRACT_NO_A|START_DATE_A|END_DATE_A|CUMULATIVA_RA |ROWNRB|REINSURED|LVL
1|CON1|2017-04-06|2017-05-05|278 000,00    |1|0|0
2|CON2|2017-05-02|2017-06-01|401 570,70    |2|0|0
3|CON3|2017-05-02|2017-06-01|549 234,82    |3|0|0
4|CON4|2017-05-02|2017-06-01|733 094,74    |4|159785,266|0
5|CON1|2017-05-06|2017-06-05|573 309,47    |5|0|0
6|CON2|2017-06-02|2017-07-01|401 570,70    |6|0|0
7|CON3|2017-06-02|2017-07-01|549 234,82    |7|0|0
8|CON4|2017-06-02|2017-07-01|733 094,74    |8|159785,266|0
```

The goal is to calculate sum of risk_amount for all childs including parent i.e. for con4 it will be con4 +con3+con2+con1 (because they last all together at least 1 day) then this sum multipie by 0.9 and minus 500000. If the result of this calculation will be >0 then for parent con5 which has child con4 has to be deducted in calculation sum for parent con5 --> con5 = con5+con4-

Comment: The code you posted has errors so won;t run at all. An attempt to fix it gets different values. So it's hard to tell quite what's going on. From your posted results, though, don't you just need to add `WHERE LVL = 0` to your final query?

Comment: Thank you, i have edited code to make it runnable. LEVEL=0 doest not solve the problem. I can sum the all childs over rownra but how to make the result of that sum be the child for another parent?